# SQL Server Identity columns with NHibernate - to use or not to use

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate

I'm working with SQL Server, and most of tables have identity columns of type int. And now, I just came across a book, that tells it's not a good idea to use this mechanism. What are the cons/pros of using identity columns when using NHibernate as ORM?

Comment: Well from a database perspective, the pro is that there is a robust way of uniquely identifying a row in a table, especially given that the table can have thousands or millions of rows etc. How else would you differentiate rows? Are there any other ID / reference columns which are unique? Is uniqueness enforced using a UNIQUE constraint?

Comment: @ChrisCannon The question and the recommendation it is based on is **not** about removing primary key, but only about how the values of the primary key are generated. NHibernate can work more efficiently when it itself manages the primary key generation.

Comment: I have dug all over google, and I do not see a good answer to this question. I think the question is open. NH wants to use GUID's... but GUIDs are horrible as primary keys in SQL Server (see http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/GUIDs-as-PRIMARY-KEYs-andor-the-clustering-key.aspx ). In our DB, which is large, we could save DOZENS of GB just by changing from GUID to identity. It is time for a better write up on this topic....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not an NHibernate expert, but as far as I understand it, using identity columns breaks the UnitOfWork and causes additional round-trips to the database.

Fabio Maulo  *(then project lead of NHibernate, I'm not sure if he still is today)* has a blog post where he explains this in detail:
[Identity: The never ending story](http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.de/2008/12/identity-never-ending-story.html)

Here is another (longer) blog post with example code:
[NH2.1.0: generators behavior explained](http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.de/2009/02/nh210-generators-behavior-explained.html)

However, note that both blog posts are about three years old and talk about NH 2.1.0, and the current version as of today is NH 3.3. But I assume that the problem as described by Fabio still exists today.

Comment: I think there is a larger issue.... Yes, the concept of "unit of work" and all is important. But SQL Server happiness is also important! GUIDs make bad primary keys in SQL Server ( http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/GUIDs-as-PRIMARY-KEYs-andor-the-clustering-key.aspx )  So in NH 3.x, is it doable to use identity? (We need to know!)

Comment: There is no reason why NHibernate can't generate SQL that returns the newly inserted identity column in the same trip that creates the record.

Comment: No, the point is: when you create 20 new objects in an UnitOfWork, NH has to make a round trip to the database for each one in order to get the ID via Identity...which kind of defeats the purpose of an UnitOfWork. With other ID generating strategies, NH only needs to make **one** single round trip at the end.

Answer (score 3):

It makes no difference if they are an identitity column or not. The role of an ORM is to map the data entities to the database not to dictate the database structure/design. I have used an implementation with identity columns and it works fine.

Comment: Yes it works. It is a question of efficiency. Using an identity column or other database controlled primary key generator prevents NHibernate from batching INSERT statements.

Comment: @Oskar - you should write an answer :) Thanks

Comment: Most databases support batch inserts in a way that returns back the identity column. See the `Output` clause in SQL Server for an example. (Whether or not NHibernate does is another matter.)